# Only "/" route is working in my Laravel Application

Tags: php, apache, laravel, routes, laravel-5

This is my Routes:

```
    Route::get('/', 'WelcomeController@index');

    Route::get('home', 'WelcomeController@index');

    Route::controllers([
        'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
        'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
    ]);
```

this is my WelcomeController:

```
   <?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

   class WelcomeController extends Controller {

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Welcome Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller renders the "marketing page" for the application and
    | is configured to only allow guests. Like most of the other sample
    | controllers, you are free to modify or remove it as you desire.
    |
    */

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application welcome screen to the user.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('welcome');
    }

  }
```

The view is just simple..

My result when i put /home is this:

[image]

Why am I doing wrong?

Something with the Apache/xampp? I just dont know.. I installed the composer again in the main folder and nothing changed.

So, if someone could help me I would be very pleased

Comment: did you create virtual host? put your htaccess file too.

Comment: like @itachi mentioned. check your htaccess setup. From your URL you are descending into public dir manually, in general setup your vhost to point to public dir rather than access public like this as you are exposing your app root

Comment: have you tried to clear route cache after adding route? (php artisan route:clear)

Answer (score 0):

The url that you went to in your browser is incorrect. From the screenshot, it shows you went to `web-service/public/home`. The url that you enter in your browser should either be:

```
web-service/public/index.php/home
```

or, if you have pretty urls enabled (url rewriting enabled), you can go to:

```
web-service/home
```